# Is there an analog of Appearing event in StatefullWidget

Tags: flutter

I come from Xamarin development to Flutter and I'm trying to find something similar of Page.Appearing event in StatefullWidget. I would like to execute some code every time when my StatefullWidget was activated.

I'm aware of the approach with `Navigator.push(...).then( code to refresh my widget )` but for this approach `Navigator.push` should be executed from my widget which is not always possible (for example if navigation happened from a child widget or a provider). What is a best practice for such case?